# mongo driver upsert: false creates new document

Tags: ruby, mongodb, upsert

I am combining both `mongomapper` and `mongo` driver in my project. I had to downgrade version of `mongo` driver, cause `mongomapper` depends on `1.12.5`. Unfortunately I've got problem with `update({search_hash}, {update_hash}, upsert: false)`, because it will create new document if searched document doesn't exist. 
Also, in documentation, no information about optional parameters of `update` is supplied.

Here is documentation:
http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/1.1.5/Mongo/Collection.html

And some code here:

```
class MongoConnector


 attr_reader :type, :collection

  def initialize(db_params, type)
    @type = type
    db = Mongo::Connection.new(connection_uri[:host], connection_uri[:port])
    @collection = db[db_params[:key]][db_params[:collection]]
  end

  def update(id, update_query)
    collection.update({ _id: bson_id(id) }, update_query, upsert: false)
  end

 private

 def bson_id(id)
    BSON::ObjectId(id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Check for record existence in advance?

Comment: Thought about this already. If there is no other option, I'll do this way.